# Technicality of Sylow's second theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory

If $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ then there exists $g\in{G}$ such that $P_{2}=gP_{1}g^{-1}$. Since $G$ could contain more elements than there are Sylow $p$-subgroups is it assumed that there could exist more than one $g\in{G}$ such that $P_{2}=gP_{1}g^{-1}$ and hence the cardinality of the orbit of $P_{1}$, where $G$ acts on the Sylow $p$-subgroups by conjugation, is equal to the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups?

Comment: The orbit of $P_1$ under the conjugation action is exactly the set of all **Sylow** $p$-subgroups, not the set of all $p$--subgroups, and not equal to a number in any case (an orbit is a collection of objects, not a number). This has nothing to do with uniqueness or lack thereof of $g$; in fact, $g$ cannot be unique, since if $g$ works, then so does $gx$ for any $x\in P_1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Apologies I did not word the question correctly, I have made some edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the for the action of $G$ by conjugation on subgroups, one orbit contains exactly the Sylow $p$-subgroups, because any two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate in $G$.

This has nothing to do with the fact that there is, in general, more than one element $g$ that conjugates a given Sylow $P_1$ into $P_2$. Recall that $gKg^{-1} = hKh^{-1}$ if and only if $h^{-1}g\in N_G(K)$. And since every subgroup normalizes itself, it follows that for every $x\in P_1$ (and possibly for more, if $P_1$ is properly contained in its normalizer), you have $gxP_1(gx)^{-1}=gP_1g^{-1} = P_2$. By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, we know that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is equal to $[G:N_G(P)]$, where $P$ is any Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. In fact, that is how the clause of the Third Sylow Theorem that establishes the number divides $|G|$ is usually proven.

Comment: Perfectly explained, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- "more than one $g \in G$ such that $P_2 = g P_1 g^{=1}$.":    This is automatic.  Let $g$ be such a $g$ and $p \in P_1$ (we may even assume $p$ is not the identity).  Then $(gp)P_1(gp)^{-1} = g P_1 g^{-1} = P_2$.  This follows from the elementary fact that $P_1$ is closed under multiplication.
- "the cardinality of the orbit of $P_1$ [under the conjugation action of $G$] is equal to the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups":  This is not automatic.  The orbit is automatically a subset of the Sylow $p$-subgroups.  Showing that the orbit is *all* of the Sylow $p$-subgroups, i.e., that the conjugation action of $G$ on the Sylow $p$-subgroups is transitive, is usually a part of the third Sylow theorem.

Comment: Huh? Sylow's Second Theorem says that if $H$ is a $p$--subgroup and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then there exists $g\in G$ such that $H\leq gPg^{-1}$. In particular, letting $H$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup, we have that any two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate. This is not usually part of the 3rd Sylow as I know them, but of the second Sylow. E.g., it is part of the Second Theorem in Hungerford and in Herstein.